# How to find index position in subarray when a value is less than zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

Very new to python so apologies for the inelegance of code

I have a numpy array with two subarrays:

```
import numpy as np
p = 0.50
gen_seq = np.random.binomial(1, p, 20).reshape(2, 10)
t_form = np.where(gen_seq == 1, 0.5, -100)
initial_w = np.insert(t_form, 0, 100, axis=1)
d_account = np.cumsum(initial_w, axis=1)
```

I am trying to find the index position of the first value that is below zero for each subarray. Any ideas?

Comment: Show each array and comment on whether that's expected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to get the *index* of the first value in each sub-array, which is less than zero; it's as simple as the following, where `a` is the array in question.

Example:

```
# Sub-array 0
(a[0,:] < 0).argmax()
# Sub-array 1
(a[1,:] < 0).argmax()
```

Or, if you'd prefer a simple loop:

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    print((a[i,:] < 0).argmax())
```

Output:

```
>>> 6
>>> 3
```

**Note:** Given the code in the original question uses `np.random`, `np.random.seed(73)` has been used in this example.

Comment: My pleasure mate, happy to help.  Would you mind please clicking the tick next to the answer to show it’s been accepted?  It’s a standard SO practice.  Cheers mate.